# how to identify the questions in the email body

Tags: python, nlp, deep-learning

I am new to the deep learning, I am solving the problem below:

I want to identify the questions present in the email body and give the text/answers suggestions for the questions present in the email.

I felt this is a **question and auto answer problem**, will **seq2seq** model will work for this type of problems?

if seq2seq will work how will I feed the data, please suggest any useful link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you tagged machine-learning, but i dont think it is the right tool for the job. Try regex:

```
import re

questions = re.findall(r"[^.?!]*?\?", text)
```

Example:

```
text = """
Dear Mr. Jameson,

I hope you are well, and that all is running smoothly at ABC Company. I miss everyone in the marketing division!

I am writing to ask if you would feel comfortable providing a positive letter of reference for me? If you are able to attest to my qualifications for employment, and the skills I attained while I was employed at ABC Company, I would sincerely appreciate it.

I am in the process of seeking a new position as a marketing manager.

Do you have any questions, or do you want a meeting in person?

I have attached an updated resume. Don’t hesitate ask for any other materials you think would be helpful.

I can be reached at jdickinson@gmail.com or (111) 111-1234. Random question?

Thank you for your consideration, and I look forward to hearing from you.

Regards,

Jane Dickinson
"""

import re

questions = re.findall(r"[^.?!]*?\?", text)

for q in questions:
    q = q.replace("\n", "")
    print(q)
```

Returns:

```
I am writing to ask if you would feel comfortable providing a positive letter of reference for me?
Do you have any questions, or do you want a meeting in person?
 Random question?
```

---

Google has a nice crashcourse on Regular Expressions:
https://developers.google.com/edu/python/regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use regex and hand check to create a labeled dataset. Some ideas from the top of my mind:

- Sentence ending with question mark "?"
- Sentence starting interrogative adverbs (why, how, which ..)

Comment: I want to use ML because all the questions cannot start with wh+ words, it can start with "can you","could you","will you" etc so I want to use ML, is there any way to use RNN/CNN to do so?

Comment: Your question was how to identify the questions and not how to train an ML algorithm to find questions. You can use ML technics once you have a labeled dataset to use it to train which ever ML classifier, and one easy way to have it is to use regex, or any other paid annotation platform.